# .htaccess - is only for PHP?

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on one website which is developed in .net. I have uploaded .htaccess files but its nt working.

Is there any new idea for that? I want that my site will be crawled with www.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.htaccess` is not just for PHP.

It's [a configuration file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) that's read by the [Apache HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org/). So if your application is not running on that server, then that file will not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` and PHP are orthogonal. One is a configuration file for Apache; the other is a scripting language. More than likely, you're using Microsoft's IIS server, not Apache.

Comment: I think going from "its not working" to "you're probably using IIS" is a bit of a leap.

Comment: @Spudley: How so? Someone writing a .NET web application is, in my opinion, most likely to be using a Microsoft web server. Microsoft web servers don't support `.htaccess`, so the OP's `.htaccess` wouldn't be "working".

Comment: @Tomalak - this is true for someone writing .NET, and yes, I see he has mentioned .net, so... yeah...   :)

Comment: @Spudley: The first sentence of the question is "I am working on one website which is developed in .net."

Comment: @Tomalk - yep, spotted that; I was probably focusing too much on the PHP part of the question.

Comment: @Spudley: I think you might have been.

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file is a configuration file for the Apache web server, and is not dependant on PHP. It typically contains settings relating to web site user permissions, friendly URL definitions, etc.

It can, however contain configuration settings for PHP, if you have settings which are in the server's PHP.ini file that you want to override for this specific web directory.

There are *many* reasons why a `.htaccess` file may not work -- it can be broken by some very subtle things, and a faulty `.htaccess` file will normally cause the whole site to stop working completely, regardless of what the error is.

In this case, the browser will usually simply show an error 500, without much useful information to help you debug it. But there will be more helpful debugging data in the server error log.

If you still struggle with it, you should post your `.htaccess` file here so we can help you debug it.

However, as @Tomalk says, if you're developing a .NET site then you're probably not using an Apache web server; you're probably using an IIS server. In that case, there are entirely different ways of setting the configuration for the server, and it won't know what to do with `.htaccess` file.